Promql query to to get all the metrics available on a node in a particular cluster
I am new to grafana, I wanted to check all the available metrics for a node in a cluster. can any one please help me with this.
count($metric{cluster="your_cluster_name"}) by (node)


This query returns all available metrics containing "node":
{__name__=~".*node.*"}


you can further reduce the output, for example only showing available metrics for a single node like this:
{name=~".node.", node="your-node-name"}
